# Why does this not work?

Tags: c#, for-loop, static, scope

Below is the code that I am using.

I would like the output be 1.65, but I get 0.

This seems like a problem of scope. However I have declared the variable `t` as static, so why is the output still 0?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static double t;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i = i + 1)
            {
                t = (i * (1 / 60));
            }
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(t));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you reset the value of T on every iteration of the loop, so the entire loop is utterly pointless and boils down to `t = (99 * 1/60)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1 / 60` will always be 0.

You are doing [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

In a division operation, you need at least one of the operands to be `double` if you want a `double` result.

Changing:

```
t = (i * (1 / 60));
```

To:

```
t = (i * (1 / 60D));
```

Or:

```
t = (i * (1D / 60));
```

Will solve the issue.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - A double _literal_ ;)

Comment: yep, looks like 2 a.m. is a time when literals look like constants :)

Answer (score 4):

When you dividing integer values, you get an integer. `1 / 60` produce zero. Cast one of operands to double `(double)1/60` to get correct double result. Or, when you are using constants like in this case, you can use double literals instead of integer literals.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing 100 divisions but only showing the messagebox once? It's the same as:

```
t = (99 * (1 / 60));
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(t));
```

Comment: This is just a snippet of some debugging code that I am using in my projectile motion simulation program! :)